# How should I fix my downspout?

Tags: roof, gutters, downspout

I just moved into this house that needs a lot of work. I noticed that the upper gutters drain onto the roof of the lower gutters and I learned that this will ruin my roof.  I was originally thinking to just connect the upper and the lower with a downspout (option A in the photo),  but after doing some more research, I started to think maybe rerouting the downspout would be a better fix (option B in the photo). Would this look kinda bad right at the entryway, though? What are your thoughts?[image]

Comment: Pour water into gutter and see which direction it flows.  From picture A choice might be best.  B looks like high point of top gutter.  Can you show a picture of back end?

Comment: The gutter should be sloped toward the outlet.  If you move it to location B, you'll want to remove the gutter from fascia and re-attach it with the appropriate slope.

Comment: As mentioned, you have to get the correct slope before moving the gutter. However, I don't believe that leaving the gutter draining onto the lower roof will ruin it. This is done all the time. Over time it may discolor some of the roofing tiles with mineral deposits  but I don't think it would cause the roof to fail. If your house needs a lot of work I suspect other home projects might be more critical to you than this one. If it's a major concern to you I would suggest you do option A.

Comment: How big are the gutters, also need pictures from the back yard.   Really no way of answering this correctly without seeing the full layout.

Comment: Also you really need video after a big rain.   I see a couple of issues but these could be easily correctable.   It is hard to tell if you have some minor adjustments to make or have a huge issue dealing with heavy rains.

Comment: You should examine if there is any advantage to where the gutter on the left drains.  A properly done downspout is not normally something that catches people's eye in my experience so I wouldn't worry much about the aesthetics.  Two thinks I'd look at are if either location makes lawn maintenance a pain (some properties have downspouts that have to be moved or cut under with a trimmer with each mowing or concrete blocks that have to be mowed or trimmed around, adding a small perpetual maintenance cost to the property.  Either pipe would mitigate uneven wear on the roof.

Comment: All other factors being equal, in winter time darker colored eavestrough on the sunny side is less likely to ice dam and two eavestroughs are less likely to dam with the same amount of precipitation.

Comment: @HoneyDo there was a similar question a week or two ago, and the general consensus was that dumping the water from a gutter above onto a roof below _will_ cause excessive wear on the roof below.

Comment: Unfortunately, VtC, as this is opinion based. Either option would work, it's up to the OP to decide which option _he_ wants.

Comment: I have a couple of spots on my house that I implemented option A and it's worked fine for years. Also, easier install than tearing into the gutter for fittings, etc. for option B.   And I agree with @FreeMan in places where and upper story gutter just dumps on to the roof DOES cause excessive wear and moss/algae growth.

Comment: Meant to add one more thing: We don't know where the gutter above the garage drains to, but if it's a proper drain line, maybe even leading to a municipal storm water drain, that would make option A even more preferable. You really really want to keep rain water away from the house.

Answer (score 1):

My house has a similar situation and when I got new gutters I inquired about option A but the guy said it would actually cause issues:

1. It's another clog point
2. It will provide shade for moss to grow and destroy the roof way faster than excess water could ever hope to achieve

If you can re-slope the gutters for option B then go for it, I don't think it would look bad. You can always paint the downspout to camouflage it or buy a pre-colored downspout which closely matches the house.

I am willing to bet you have much more pressing matters to tend to which don't involve messing with gutters that work as designed :-)

Comment: I would agree that there's nothing wrong with the downspout at option B.